# how to make title bar less window in mfc by code?

Tags: mfc

how to make title bar less window in mfc by code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
ModifyStyle (WS_CAPTION, 0); // to hide
ModifyStyle (0, WS_CAPTION); // to show
```

To remove it earlier Override `PreCreateWindow()` and remove `WS_SYSMENU`

Comment: @mmonem I call `Create` with `WS_VISIBLE | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_SIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX`. If I then use `ModifyStyle(WS_CAPTION, NULL)` I get a sizable, maximizable window with no titlebar, **but** only after moving the window, either programmatically or manually. I tried to override `PreCreateWindow` and the effect is not the same.

Comment: I am sorry, @pelesl, I abandoned using MFC years ago so I can't add any value here

Comment: @mmonem I just started, because I need to write in C/C++ and need a Windows GUI (image zooming/panning). Are there alternatives? My only other experience is straight-up API calls.

Comment: If you are just started and you don't have other considerations, I recommend you to give up MFC totally. After 13 years of heavy MFC'ing, since 4 years, I totally converted to Qt which is more effecient in terms of software development time than MFC.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add, calling:

```
SetWindowPos(nullptr, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_FRAMECHANGED | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOZORDER);
```

after ModifyStyle() applies the settings (at least for dialog-based applications).